# Textbox in Sweet Alert not focus-able while on bootstrap modal in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I've a sweetalert box that's containing a text box. The sweetalert is opened on a bootstrap modal box. in Firefox, I'm trying to click in the text box but it is not getting the focus.

Here is my Sweet Alert code:

```
swal(
        {
            title:              "Create New Design",
            input:              "text",
            showCancelButton:   true,
            inputPlaceholder:   "Title",
            preConfirm: function(input)
            {
                // code to validate the input
            }
        });
```

And this is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: First of all, you're using [SweetAlert**2**](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2), not SweetAlert. Those two projects are different.This issue could help: https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/issues/374

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot

Answer (score 5):

As per the known issue given by **@limonte** in the comment, the Boostrap modal box has a function called enforceFocus that immediately puts focus on the modal itself as soon as we try to focus into an element that is not wrapped in the BS modal box.

So for now what I've done is unbind that **focusin.bs.modal** event from the document like below. It works fine.

```
jQuery('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    jQuery(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

We don't have any other solutions to do that except one another.

We can possible override that particular method using below line:

```
jQuery.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { };
```

Comment: `jQuery.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { };` works, jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lng89tq/34/